# Introductory Text for GAM

Tags: references, generalized-additive-model

I'm looking for a text to help someone who uses GLMs in practice become familiar/comfortable with GAMs.  Online or physical textbook would be fine.  I am approaching this as a practitioner, so I would prefer practical to theoretical, but I'm confident I have the background to digest a more theoretical text if it happens to be particularly worthwhile.

I also use R, almost exclusively.  If you happen to know of some R oriented texts/tutorials that'd be really appreciated.

Comment: I would go with Simon Wood's [Generalised Additive Models: an introduction with R](http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~sw283/igam/index.html). Even though **mgcv** has moved on a lot from what was used in this book (See `citation(package = "mgcv")` for some of the more recent proper papers on the methods), this remains one of the best books I know for learning about GAMs (and GLMs) with a practical side in R and a theoretical side.

Comment: I ordered Gavin's book.  It appears to be the perfect suggestion.  I agree that he should have made it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Buja et al., (1989) give a nice overview of GAMs in the context of other additive nonparametric smoothing models. If I recall correctly, most of their examples can be easily done in R using existing packages.

Buja, A., Hastie, T., and Tibshirani, R. (1989). Linear Smoothers and Additive Models. *The Annals of Statistics*, 17(2):453–510.

Answer (score 2):

I thought Michael Clark's overview is excellent:
https://m-clark.github.io/generalized-additive-models/

A great short (very short) introduction to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Hastie & Tibshirani's original textbook is still a great read IMO: Hastie, T. & Tibshirani, R. (1990) *Generalized Additive Models*, Chapman & Hall. I personally found it much easier to follow than Simon Wood's text, even if the latter is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this introductory video on GAM that I thought was helpful and easy to follow:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXDYapfalt4

Answer (score 1):

Not a text but I found this to be a great resource for GAMs using R: https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/

It leads you through the nature of fitting a GAM without getting into the maths involved.

Answer (score 0):

See chapter 3 in "Mixed effects models and extensions in ecology with R. 
A Zuur, EN Ieno, N Walker, AA Saveliev, GM Smith"

Ch3 provides a really basic intro to GAM in both the GAM and MGCV packages. In further chapters the book covers a lot of the things you might do with GAM and goes into  GAMM, and zero-inflated GAM.

Its a great intro and also helpful for advanced applications.