# What log-likelihood function do you use when doing a Poisson regression with continuous response?

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution

I am given $N$ observations of pairs of covariates and response $(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i)$. When the response are non-negative integers, by doing Poisson regression I am modelling $y_i \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\mu_i)$ as Poisson random variables with mean $\mu_i$, such that $\ln(\mu_i)$ is a linear function of the covariate $\mathbf{x}_i$. A maximum likelihood estimator for the coefficients of $\mathbf{x}_i$ maximises the Poisson log-likelihood:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i \ln(\mu_i) - \mu_i)$$

I have seen references to doing Poisson regression with non-negative, non-integers, e.g. [How does a Poisson distribution work when modeling continuous data and does it result in information loss?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/how-does-a-poisson-distribution-work-when-modeling-continuous-data-and-does-it-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In this case, what log-likelihood function is used? Do you still use the above function but allow $y_i$ to take the non-integer values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. In fact, since proper Poisson model would be incorrect in here because of dealing with continuous outcome, you'll be using quasi-Poisson model.

It is called [quasi-likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-likelihood) and was described for the first time by Wedderburn (1974):

> To define a likelihood we have to specify the form of distribution of
>   the observations, but to define a quasi-likelihood function we need
>   only specify a relation between the mean and variance of the
>   observations and the quasi-likelihood can then be used for estimation.

You can find some more description and examples in paper by McCullagh (1983) and [handbooks on GLM's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/is-there-a-glm-bible/209536#209536).

In case of quasi-Poisson model, the quasi-likelihood is

$$ y \log \mu - \mu $$

where $y \ge 0$ and $\mu > 0$ as described in McCullagh (1983).

---

Wedderburn, R. W. (1974). [Quasi-likelihood functions, generalized linear models, and the Gauss—Newton method.](http://matt-wand.utsacademics.info/webStatSem/Wedderburn.pdf) Biometrika, 61(3), 439-447.

McCullagh, P. (1983). [Quasi-likelihood functions.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176346056) The Annals of Statistics, 59-67.